# Use IN argument in IF statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I already tried using the IN argument on a Select Statement like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM msgs WHERE user1 IN ('$var1','$var2') AND user2 IN ('$var1','$var2')";
```

Does this work on an IF Statement as well like

```
if(user1 IN ('$var1','$var2') AND user2 IN ('$var1','$var2')){
```

And if not, is there an alternate way to achieve something similar like this in an IF Statement?

## UPDATE

The `msg` table somewhat looks like this :

```
accid  |  user1  |  user2  |  message  |
1         mark      edward    asasdsadsad
2         edward    mark      asdaqwdksjadhkq
3         mark      sherlock   sadasdadsad
```

I want to make an `IF STATEMENT` to identify whether user1 is mark/edward `AND` user2 is mark/edward - in that way I could confirm that the two have sent messages back-and-forth. Normally I could go with `IN` through `SELECT`, but in this case I must really use `IF` statement for some reasons. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: I'm trying to identify whether the user's id is "involved" on the table, like whether it exists either in the user1 table, or in the user2.

Comment: Function `in_array`

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Just an observation... to check whether a value exists *either* in ... *or* in ...,  that seems to suggest we'd want an `OR` condition rather than an `AND` condition.  I'm not saying the `AND` is wrong, it just strikes me odd to describe that the operation as checking "*either* ... *or*" when there's an `AND` in there.

Comment: I'm confused that the SQL has curly braces? Or has PHP secretly introduced 'IN'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IN` operator is a standard SQL operator; that's valid in a SQL statement.

But that's not a PHP operator. No, the PHP `if` statement isn't correct.
PHP comparison operators are documented here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Not at all clear what `user1` is a reference to.  If that's a variable name, it should be preceded by a dollar sign.

The equivalent of that SQL expression in PHP would be something like this:

```
if( ( $user1 == $var1 or $user1 == $var2) and ( $user2 == $var1 OR $user2 == $var2 ) ) {
```

Note: In MySQL, by default, string comparisons are case insensitive. (It really depends on the collation of the expressions.) If we are comparing strings, to get case insensitive comparisons in PHP, we can use the `strcasecmp` function in place of the `==` comparison operator. Documented here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php

---

As *u_mulder* suggested in a comment, if we are okay with a case sensitive comparison for strings, and if we put `$var1` and `$var2` into an array, we could make use of the `in_array` function, documented here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php